# Creating reusable child views in Titanium Alloy (A

Tags: titanium, custom-controls, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm new to Appcelerator Titanium, so one of the considerations that popped into my mind was this: how do I create reusable custom controls for use in Alloy? Take for example in Android:

[image]

The `ColorPicker` is a 3rd-party library that allows me to add it as a control to the .xml file so long as I reference the library. I would also be able to create my own controls and either reuse them locally or distribute them as an external library. Is there a similar concept for Titanium, more specifically for Alloy (i.e. the xml and all)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is the concept of creating widgets and which can be reused locally in the projects. There are alot of widgets already available.

One of the important widgets for creation of the application [Font Awsome Widget](https://github.com/MattMcFarland/com.mattmcfarland.fontawesome).

You can see the source code as well and check its implementation.